# ifft and fft changes the value?

Tags: python, numpy, fft

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9Ymr.png)

I can not understand why the same magnitude spectrum made by ifft is different with original magnitude spectrum...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wP9ZX.png)

It is the origianal magnitude specturm and there above, it is fourier transformed with the left heart image.

When I substract two of them, it was not 0!!
Could you tell me what is wrong??

Comment: Can you show the code producing these results?

Comment: And please copy-paste the code, don’t post screen shots of text. When you say “not zero”, are the values significantly distinct from 0? Numerical computations always have rounding errors, which will make it so that IFFT(FFT(x)) is not exactly x, but still very close.